# can i decide the column names of a SELECT statement from another SELECT statement

Tags: sql

can i decide the column names of a SELECT statement from another SELECT statement

like this:

```
SELECT ( SELECT SELECTSTMTA FROM a
         JOIN b
         ON a.ID=b.ID
         WHERE a.ID=300019  ) 
FROM c
WHERE lkpgroup= 300019
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either select `ALL` columns or `explicit` columns by explicitly requesting them, eg)

`Select ColA, ColB from Table1`

Your query would fail because your saying "Select  (subquery)". You need to select 'something' and use the keyword `from`.

I suggest you explicitly call the columns in your subquery, then use select * to return the entire dataset of your subquery. EG)

```
SELECT * FROM
  ( SELECT ColA FROM a
     JOIN b
     ON a.ID=b.ID
  )query
WHERE query.ColA = 300019
```

So to answer your question, No. You cannot use a select query to decide which column's to return. - This would be like telling a compiler to write a program!

However, you would use * to return all columns from a subquery, table or view.

Comment: If it answers your question accept as the answer :)

Comment: Any reason for the downvote?

Comment: maybe because it won't run , 2 times FROM on the base, no alias for the subselect ... etc ...

Comment: Ahh! Thank you for pointing that out! I totally forgot to check the SQL -_-... Edited.